# Why are match statements more picky about reference types than function parameters?

Tags: rust, reference, match, borrow

In Rust, one often sees functions that take `&str` as a parameter.

```rust
fn foo(bar: &str) {
    println!("{}", bar);
}
```

When calling functions like this, it is perfectly fine to pass in a `String` as an argument by referencing it.

```rust
let bar = String::from("bar");
foo(&bar);
```

Strictly speaking, the argument being passed is an `&String` and the function is expecting an `&str`, but Rust (as one would hope) just figures it out and everything works fine. However, this is not the case with match statements. If I try and use the same `bar` variable as before in a match statement, the naive usage will not compile:

```rust
match &bar {
    "foo" => println!("foo"),
    "bar" => println!("bar"),
    _ => println!("Something else")
};
```

Rustc complains that it was expecting an `&str` but received an `&String`. The problem and solution are both very obvious: just borrow `bar` more explicitly with `.as_str()`. But this brings me to the real question: why is this the case?

If Rust can figure out that an `&String` trivially converts to an `&str` in the case of function arguments, why can't it do the same thing with match statements? Is this the result of a limitation of the type system, or is there hidden unsafety in fancier borrowing with match statements? Or is this simply a case of a quality of life improvement getting integrated into some places but not others? I'm sure someone knowledgeable about type systems has an answer, but there seems to be very little information about this little quirk of behavior on the internet.

Comment: This is called "deref coercion" - `&String` can be de-referenced into an `&str`, and the compiler will automatically do this for you when an `&str` is expected. The actual issue you describe is probably just a limitation of the compiler.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The technical reason it doesn't work is because the `match` scrutinee is not a [coercion site](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/type-coercions.html#coercion-sites). Function arguments, as shown in your `foo(&bar)` example, are possible coercion sites; and it allows you to pass a `&String` as a `&str` because of `Deref` coercion.

A possible reason why its not a coercion site is that there's no clear type that it should be coerced to. In your example you'd like it to be `&str` since that matches the string literals, but what about:

```
match &string_to_inspect {
    "special" => println!("this is a special string"),
    other => println!("this is a string with capacity: {}", other.capacity()),
};
```

One would like the `match` to act like `&str` to match the literal, but because the match is on a `&String` one would expect `other` to be a `&String` as well. How to satisfy both? The next logical step would be for each pattern to coerce as required, which has been much desired... but it opens a whole can of worms since `Deref` is user-definable. See [deref patterns](https://github.com/rust-lang/lang-team/blob/master/projects/deref-patterns.md) from the Rust lang-team for more info.

Answer (score 0):

https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/type-coercions.html says:

> ## Coercion sites
>
> A coercion can only occur at certain coercion sites in a program; these are typically places where the desired type is explicit or can be derived by propagation from explicit types (without type inference). Possible coercion sites are:
>
> - [...]
> - Arguments for function calls
>
>   The value being coerced is the actual parameter, and it is coerced to the type of the formal parameter.

but not a `match` scrutinee.

> ## Coercion types
>
> Coercion is allowed between the following types:
>
> - [...]
> - `&T` or `&mut T` to `&U` if `T` implements `Deref<Target = U>`.